# Is September a good time to sow chili pepper seeds in Hong Kong?

Tags: peppers, chili, sowing, late-sowing

I want to grow some habanero chili and jalapeño chili, but it is already September in Hong Kong. Although people said that chilis can't stand winter, I suspect the recent winter of Hong Kong is relatively warm (due to global warming) that the chili can withstand it. Should I sow it now or even in early October?

Here's the weather information for Hong Kong in 2010.

Because chili tends to love warm temperature for germination, I can use a raptile warm pad to heat it up. But can a young seedling or adult plant withstand the temperature in winter?

[image]

Comment: January lows of 15C?? We get those kind of lows in July -- midsummer! I suspect your peppers will be fine in such a "winter", but I'll defer to the chili experts here for a proper answer. (Mine survive but don't actually make much fruit in our "summer" that sounds like your "winter"...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are going to be fine. Most people grow peppers as annuals because they have winter frosts, or cool dark winters. From the point of view of peppers (and tomatoes which are very similar) most of those months are ideal. They will probably grow a little slower in the coolest months but with good sunlight and the right amount of water they'll be fine - your coolest months are warmer than what I plant my pepper seed in, here in Texas. Also your hottest temperatures aren't as extreme as what we get.

Are these in pots? Remember to use a tray due to your high rainfall in some months (probably teaching a grandmother to suck eggs!); and add water in the dry months.

The closest climate where I've seen peppers growing, is in Costa Rica (maritime tropical with a nominal 'rainy season' although it rains all year). They did fine outside and were being grown with tomatoes,etc. to feed a small hotel kitchen.